# UWP Windows Mobile 10 timeout issue in consuming WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, uwp

Several weeks ago we encountered with an issue concerning the consuming of wcf service in uwp application. We use the last version of framework - Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (14393).
So, when we invoke wcf methods on uwp app, everything works ok, if request takes no longer than 5 minutes. But its not just timeout error, because timeouts are properly setup on both sides (uwp client and wcf service). We debugged the service and service methods actually return results and no error is happened there, but client doesn't receive the response and nothing is happening at all till the real timeout (SendTimeout and ReceiveTimeout). This behavior was noticed on the Windows Mobile 10 emulators and Windows Mobile 10 devices. On the desktop there is no such operation time limitation.
We need our app to wait for processing pretty longtime wcf-operations (longer than 5 min) on WM10. Its seems to be a built-in timeout. Please, help who knows something about this strange behavior. We would appreciate your help

Comment: The question is hard to understand. My interpretation is that you are running into some hard 5-minute timeout on a WCF (thereby an http request) - which is a very long timeout by http/wcf convention. Can you clarify what is going on and what the need is?

Comment: theMayer, thanks for reply. Sorry for such odd description of issue. Let me explain you what we do in steps:
1. We have uwp app and it consumes wcf service.
2. On wcf service and uwp client we set SendTimeout and ReceiveTimeout to 15 minutes;
3. We invoke a service method which is executing more than 10 minutes, while client waits for response from it. When the method is completing and returns result, the client is still waiting for response, and after 15 minutes the TimeoutException is thrown. (When we run uwp on desktop and invoke service method, client receives the response from it).

Comment: We use wcf where some methods implement preparing of quite large data which may take some time, and then return long value (size of those data) to the client.

Comment: Yes - yes you understood correctly, its really long timeout for wcf, but why this limitation concerns mobile and not desktop

Comment: Why don't you issue one request to start the process, getting back a process identifier- then issue subsequent requests to check the status of the process- when the process is done, then issue a third request to get the result?

Comment: theMayer, yes, thank u, we eventually decided to use this approach